# Critical Error "Start Menu Not Working" - After changing ProfileImagePath through regedit (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, start-menu

### My Current Situation :

- I tried to change the name of the user folder for my main account.
- Windows Explorer didn't allow me to change the subfolder directly,
  so I tried changing the path value of ProfileImagePath through the Registry Editor from a new
  administrator account (sub)
- After changes to the registry were made, I logged out of the sub admin account, restarted my laptop and signed back in through the main user.

#### I had the following complications:

1. My icons are nowhere to be found yet by BG and dark theme remained.

   - *fixed by changing the path value back to the original in sub admin,
     though my icons are in the wrong places*
2. Critical Error : The Start menu isn't working.
   (!! still unresolved)

Apart from this, all my applications (even Edge and Google Chrome) are working properly.

> Honest Mistake : I failed to backup the registry
> (I only exported it after the said complications have arised)

#### Few things I've tried:

- ###### sfc /scannow and dism in Safe Mode w/ Networking

  > *scan shows no integrity violations*
  > *for dism, it said "operation complete" but no change after restart*
- ###### restart application identity service

  > *changes cannot be applied, it shows "Access Denied" in both admin accounts??*
- ###### reset tile database

  - *cannot find the database folder*
- ###### re-register start menu

  > *used a batch file from the bleepingcomputers forum (link below)*,
  > *also tried GetAppxchange in administrative Powershell*

Attempt 1:

```
Get-appxpackage -all *shellexperience* -packagetype bundle |% 
{add-appxpackage -register -disabledevelopmentmode ($_.installlocation + “\appxmetadata\appxbundlemanifest.xml”)}
```

> This did not return anything.

Attempt 2:

```
Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach 
{Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register “$($_.InstallLocation)AppXManifest.xml”}
```

> This returned "Cannot find path ...\AppXManifest.xml" because it does not exist"
> I'm assuming this has something to do with the AppxPackage it's been referring to?

#### Other remarks:

- System restore and System Image Recovery - non-applicable since I have no restore points
- Start Menu Troubleshooter - no longer exists

Other than the questions from this forum and Microsoft community,
here are some specific links I've been to:

- https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/729498/critical-error-your-start-menu-isnt-working-after-user-profile-recreation/
- https://howtofixwindows.com/windows-10-critical-error-your-start-menu-isnt-working/
- https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/125068-how-to-fix-your-windows-10-start-menu-reset-tile-database

#### What I'm planning to do now:

- Will copy the %localappdata% from the sub admin to the main,
  Currently copying the AppData\Local folder from my main onto a hard drive for backup

  - Edit : On second thought, this might not be a good idea since the two Local folders have different subfolders and I'm afraid replacing my main Local folder altogether might cause errors for some apps

---

I have spent hours trying to find a solution. I would love to fix this as soon as possible.

I would appreciate anyone who would give their time to help and tell me if I'm missing anything.

Thank You!

Comment: In order to set up a new user account, would I need to copy the contents of my whole User folder? and when re-installing Windows, I'd like to ask if there will be no data loss?

Comment: Oh, okay! Thank you so much for your suggestions. I'll try them out when I'm available. One last thing, might I ask what it means to have 'bashed' my user account profile? I'd like to avoid causing it again next time.

Comment: Got it. I'll make sure to backup my files properly then. But I think I'll need a hard drive since I have used up about 205 GB on my laptop. Thank you so much!

Comment: You cannot rename the `%UserProfile%` directory through the Registry - all you're going to do is corrupt the User Profile, which you've done. You can try undoing the changes you've done, but the only for sure way to fix User Profile corruption is to create a [new](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/fix-a-corrupted-user-profile-in-windows-1cf41c18-7ce3-12f9-8e1d-95896661c5c9) user and move all data over to the new User Profile.

Comment: There is no supported way to change this cosmetic thing. Normally you woukld log on as admin, create a new account, and use Windows to copy the profile. So *Settings - System - About - Advanced System Settings link - Advanced tab - under User Profiles - Settings - Copy To*. You can't be logged on as source or destination user.

Comment: I am unable to copy user profiles through the settings as the above user suggested since the options are greyed out for me(?). I was not logged into the source and destination users. 
I'm currently trying to move the files I need to the sub administrator user account I mentioned since I realized that I don't essentially have to keep everything from the main account.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to delete the whole DefaultAccount key folder under

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CloudStore\Store\Cache\DefaultAccount

Sign out, sign in.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).